# htaccess - removes index.php, but not index.php when index.php?z=abc

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing

http:// domain.com/index.php -> http:// domain.com/   - OK

http:// domain.com/index.php?z=abc -> http:// domain.com/index.php?z=abc   - not OK, stays the same.
This works using the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

How to modify this code so that

```
http:// domain.com/index.php?z=abc -> http:// domain.com/?z=abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will take care of the query string automatically. All you need is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The [R=301] will break POST requests (form data lost), but leaving it out will not affect the address bar.  For this reason, you would want to avoid doing this kind of rewrite if (ever) POSTing to index.

Comment: @Umbrella Most servers default to 301, anyway. And since he doesn't want `/index.php` to be shown in the address bar, I doubt he'll be posting to it.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen A reasonable doubt, but since the OP opened a new question about this breaking his POSTs, I figured the reminder might be helpful to someone else finding this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try the modified RewriteCond below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```