# PHP post sending

Tags: php, html

I have a simple post form that is sending data from one page to the other, however when I press submit, the process.php says no username and password have been entered. I feel like I am missing something stupidly obvious. What am I doing wrong here?

Login.php

```
 <form action="login_process.php" method="POST"> 
        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <input name="username" type="text"><br>  
        <input name="password" type="password"><br>  
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">  
 </form>
```

login_process.php

```
    var_dump($_POST['username']);
    echo '<br>';
    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {  
       echo 'U heeft geen gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord ingevoerd!'.'<br>';  
       echo 'username', $_POST['username']; 
       echo '<br>password', $_POST['password'];
       exit;  
    } else {
       $sql = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '"  . $_POST['username'] . "' AND `password` = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'";
       echo 'Gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord goed ingevoerd.';
    }
```

Comment: I have just tested this and it works, are you sure that the files are in the same directory?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` return ?

Comment: SamSwift웃 Yeah I just downloaded and double checked it, they're in the same directory.

Daan the var_dump gives me ''NULL''

Comment: @SemAbraham, instead of relocation, use `#` as the form action and `isset($_POST) { var_dump($_POST); }` on the Login.php page to check that values are being set, then you can see if it is a problem on the server, or on the form

Comment: Alright it did dump the username and pass. So.. they're not being sent with the form? This is what it dumped: array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(5) "admin" }

Comment: If i change the form action to GET everything works. But that's not really recommended with password handling :P

Comment: if you use if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) your program will never enter in this block because if you press submit $_POST['username'] will be set automatically but it will be null. Try using if ($_POST['username']=="" || $_POST['password']=="") instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! Alot of the confusion came completely from my side. I had an .htaccess file in my root which was apparently blocking all POST data. I removed the .htaccess file to test and the POST data was being given to the login_process.php neatly.

See this post for more info:
[Seems like POST values are lost when .htaccess RewriteRule used. GET values are OK. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826861/seems-like-post-values-are-lost-when-htaccess-rewriterule-used-get-values-are)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need -

```
if ($_POST['username']=="" || $_POST['password']==""){
   echo 'U heeft geen gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord ingevoerd!'.'<br>';  
   echo 'username', $_POST['username']; 
   echo '<br>password', $_POST['password'];
   exit;  
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '"  . $_POST['username'] . "' AND `password` = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'";
   echo 'Gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord goed ingevoerd.';
}
```

But your code will have lot of security issues as someone can try to hack your application by inserting *Programming* logic in username and password .

The best way is -
1. Use strip_tags($input) - this will remove tags from inputs as username or passwords are not supposed to have tags ;
2. Do not store username password as it is in your DB as you are doing above , use encrypted form of text .

Comment: Encryption can be applied something like this -                                   <?php
echo "MD5 Hash: " . md5("password");
echo "SHA1 Hash: " . sha1("password");
?>

Comment: My login_process page only has this in it currently: if(isset($_POST)) { var_dump($_POST); } and it still dumps NULL. So i'm not sure what's up with that, and i'm also aware the password storing is wrong, but I want to get this working first before I implement any security.

Comment: can you please just do this at the top of your php file and tell me what result you get - echo $_POST['username'] ; echo $_POST['password'];

Comment: And tell me results for this as well, Paste it at the top of your page- echo  $_REQUEST['username'] ; echo  $_REQUEST['password']