# PHP POST just not working for some reason

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

Trying to make a simple login page, here's the form:

```
    <form action="admin/login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-container">
            <span class="label">Username:</span>
            <input class="login-input" type="text" name="user" required>

            <span class="label">Password:</span>
            <input class="login-input" type="password" name="pass" required>
        </div>

        <input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

Here's the login page:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo $_POST['user'];
?>
```

I just get this printed out:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /var/www/html/admin/login.php on line 6
```

I have no idea what is going on and i've tried everything.

Comment: file extension is missing in form action

Comment: action="admin/login.php" ???

Comment: I have my .htaccess file set to remove extensions. And it takes me to the page, as it shows that error? The code for login.php is in my question above.

Comment: then your .htaccess could be the reason as well. disable the .htaccess and implement the changes (add ".php"). if it works, it's your .htaccess

Comment: use if(isset($_POST)

Comment: I smell a wrong redirection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seems like POST values are lost when .htaccess RewriteRule used. GET values are OK. How to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826861/seems-like-post-values-are-lost-when-htaccess-rewriterule-used-get-values-are)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you guys were right that it was an issue with the .htaccess file.

I just needed to add a slash after the action path:

```
action="admin/login/"
```

That's it!

Comment: This shouldn't matter if you have a correct .htaccess rule ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change Action from `action="admin/login"` to `action="admin/login.php"` then submit.
You are hitting `login.php` directly from URL that is why it is showing undefined user because user is defined as a post variable