# Losing "php://input" after a mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am using a `mod_rewrite` to forward all api calls to `apiHandler.php` with the follow `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /apiHandler.php
```

The problem is, inside `apiHandler.php`, I'm losing the data from `php://input`.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$requestBody = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo json_encode($requestBody);
exit();
```

Whenever I hit my api with: `"http://localhost:80/api/testing"` I get back a null from `$requestBody`, but when I use `"http://localhost:80/apiHandler.php"`, I get back the correct value from `$requestBody`.

[image: doesn't work]
[image: works]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else is having trouble with this or a similar problem, adding the `redirect` flag, with http status code `307`, to my rewrite rule worked for me. I saw the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839676/6128284).

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /apiHandler.php [R=307]
```